# Continue scroll when there is no scrolling available just like in Google Maps

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, slidingmenu

I am trying to replicate the google maps using AndroidSlidingUpPanel.

[image]

My problem is the panel cannot be drag and its just the listview is scrolling.

As you can see in google maps. the list view is not scrollable until the panel fully expand.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    > 

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/app_secondary_color"
        app:contentInsetLeft="14dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="14dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:panelHeight="140dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/maps_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dragView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/hospital_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

as JASON G PETERSON said

this what i tried

***Update***

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    private boolean interceptTouch = true;

    public void InterceptTouch(boolean bool) {
        interceptTouch = bool;
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
     if(interceptTouch){
        return false;
    }else{
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if(interceptTouch){
        return false;
    }else{
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
    }
}
```

on my activity

```
mLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View view, float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelCollapsed(View view) {
                LogUtil.d("COLLAPSED");
                mListView.InterceptTouch(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelExpanded(View view) {
                LogUtil.d("EXPANDED");
                mListView.InterceptTouch(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelAnchored(View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelHidden(View view) {

            }
        });
```

the problem is  mListView.InterceptTouch(false); was not working properly, specialy when you do a quick scroll the panel collapse.

I just want the panel to collapse when the first row is shown first and the user scrolls down, just like the pull to refresh effect. Any help?

***//UPDATE 3***

I added this. but the panel does not slide when i am dragging. I need to drag again then the panel sliding take effect. Why?

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

    int cFirstVisibleItem = 0;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        interceptScroll(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (view.getChildCount() > 0) {

            cFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            LogUtil.d("GET firstVisibleItem :" + firstVisibleItem);
            LogUtil.d("GET Y :" + view.getChildAt(0).getY());
            interceptScroll(view);
        }
    }

    public void interceptScroll(AbsListView view) {
        if (view.getChildAt(0).getY() == 0 && cFirstVisibleItem == 0) {
            mLayout.setSlidingEnabled(true);
            mListView.InterceptTouch(true);

            LogUtil.d("intercept");
        } else {
            mListView.InterceptTouch(false);
            mLayout.setSlidingEnabled(false);
            LogUtil.d("dont intercept");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because your ListView is first consuming the touch event. You can extend ListView and then add conditions for when and when not to pass the touch event to the sliding panel with a snippet like:

```
    @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if (/*Your conditions.*/) {

                return false;//Don't intercept. Let sliding panel get touch.

            }

            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event); //Don't let sliding panel get touch.


}
```